# cross object dependency in screen flow

Tags: screen-flow

I have two custom picklist fields for account ( status ) and opportunity ( customer-detail ).
When creating an opp with a screen flow I want to show different customer-detail values according to the account status.
How can I achieve this ?

For ex:

If I create an opp for an active account, customer-detail values should be existing-customer-rent or existing-customer-purchase

If I create an opp for a passive account, customer-detail values should be new-customer-rent or new-customer-purchase

Comment: Where are you going to place this screen flow? From Account's record page?

Comment: its in account record page, create opp flow

Comment: Does the account only have 2 status options? For example, only "Active" and "Passive"? or it has more. I am asking because, what if the status is other than these 2 then what would the Customer Detail picklist would show?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on your post; What I know is that you are going to  place/use this flow in Account object. I am also assuming you have built screen flows before.

so in this case, your **recordId** variable can be type **record** and associate it with **Account** object. Now you can use this variable to access the Account's status.

In your screen flow, you create 'New Resource' -> Resource Type should be 'Choice'. An example below:

[image: New choice resource creation]

You are going to create 4 of these; (Existing Customer Purchase, Existing Customer Rent, New Customer Purchase, New Customer Rent). **Note**: Make sure your Choice Value is the API name of the picklist field. In the example here, I am assuming both label and value have the same value.

Once you have created 4 of these, in your screen component you can drag and drop "Picklist" component in and configure the choices for the picklist component.

[image: Picklist component configuration]

In the example above, I am showing the picklist options to show, when the account status is 'Active'. So in your case, you will need to add 2 picklist component. One for active and another for passive. Where your passive picklist, will have 2 other choice that you created earlier.

Once this is done, should have 2 picklist components stacked on top of each other. Now for the final step, you should add a component visibility to both the picklist component. Each to show, based on the Account's status.

[image: Visibility Filter]

In your case, the second picklist component, should show when the Account's status is 'Passive'.

With these, when you are launching the screen flow from account record, this flow can automatically limit the picklist options based on the account's status. I hope this helps. If you need clarification on any steps, feel free to add a comment. I will edit the post to add more details.

Lastly, of course you have to add other flow elements in to extract the values and perform your own required logic.

Comment: thank you for your time, I created the components as you show, but when I create a create record element how can I map the customer-detail field with the 2 picklist components that I have.

Comment: You can add a decision element to check what is the account's status before the create record element. Based on the status, you can create the opportunity by taking the value from the one of the picklist component. Example, if Account status=Active, then I will take the value for Opportunity's customer detail from the Picklist component (which shows when Account status=Active). If Account status=passive, then I will get the value for customer detail from the picklist component which shows when account status=passive.

Comment: finally it works, thanks a lot